# How to transfer email from godaddy to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

Here's my scenario:

- I bought a domain from goddady
- I set up email on godaddy as an addon
- I hosted a web application on AWS
- In order to secure my API calls I needed to transfer my domain from godaddy to AWS (I should have bought the domain on AWS to begin with but I didn't know I could do that)
- I have successfully transferred my domain
- Now my email (obviously) doesn't work anymore.

My question is: do I have to transfer email over to AWS as well, or is there just some setting that I will have to change on godaddy to point to AWS now?  Is there a similar service on AWS (hosted email) that I can use?

Comment: You don't need to transfer your domain, you just point your domain to AWS name server. If your AWS account come with email, then you can use AWS email server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have moved the domain into AWS, you need to move/create the MX(Mail exchange) records in route 53 too. Just create an MX record type entry in route 53 with name as your domain name and values with the list of mail servers that you can grab from godaddy. Here is the link to find how you can get the mail records form godaddy

https://au.godaddy.com/help/checking-and-managing-my-mx-records-7590

For more information about how to add MX records. follow this link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#MXFormat